# Window in tkinter automatically closes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some code here that I copied from the tkinter tutorials so I am sure it is 100% correct:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

It is supposed to work but instead, when I run the program it shows the window for about 1 millisecond and then closes immediately. How do I fix this?

I am using Python 3.8.

Comment: Doesn't do that when I run it, and the `Button` works, too.

Comment: Error is not reproducible, voting to close the question.

Comment: @Yatin OP mentioned the python version in an answer/ comment which got deleted.

Answer (score -1):

`mainloop()` should be called on a `tk.Tk` object but in your code `app` is a `tk.Frame` object.  So, try ...

```
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That doesn't matter - the mainloop behaves the same no matter which widget you call it on.

Comment: `mainloop()` is a universal method and can be called on any tkinter widget.